# Matrix norm for two matrices simultaneously close to spectral radius

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-radius, matrix-norms

Suppose $A$ and $B$ have the same spectral radius $\rho$. We can find a norm $\| \cdot \|_A $ s.t. $\|A\|_A - \epsilon < \rho$. We can likewise find a another norm s.t. $\|B\|_B - \epsilon < \rho$. Under what conditions can we find a norm $\|\cdot\|_*$ such that both

$$\|A\|_* - \epsilon < \rho $$

and

$$\|B\|_* - \epsilon < \rho$$

Having done some digging it would seem one sufficient condition would be for $A$ and $B$ to be normal and another for the matrices to be simultaneously diagonalizable. Is there a necessary and sufficient condition?

Comment: It is also sufficient for $A$ and $B$ to be simultaneously upper triangularizable, but if normality is enough then this isn't a necessary condition.

Comment: Do you know if there exists a pair $A,B$ where there is no such norm?  Off the top of my head, I would think that 
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}, \quad \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}
$$
might be such a pair

Comment: Notably, any norm satisfies $\|AB\| \leq \|A\| \, \|B\|$, so we must have
$$
\|B\| \geq \frac{\|AB\|}{\|A\|} \geq \frac{\rho(AB)}{\rho + \epsilon}
$$
it follows that $\rho(AB) \leq \rho^2$ is a **necessary** condition, but I don't know if this condition is also sufficient.